# Optimal way to read as CSV a text file in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a text file with below content

```
f  56.2MiB  2y109d DATA\3DSMaxInstall\Athena\Components\AGS\3.1\Autodesk Genuine Service.msi
d        0   2y74d BUILDS\Install\Glue\User\CM Installer
f   168KiB  2y337d SOURCES\FireDrive\Data\File\ClicV2\9.0.0.1329\Bpk Pvt Inst.msm
f  15.3MiB  2y347d Finder\Perl58.zip
```

I want this to load as dataframe in below format.

```
File|  Size  |Duration|Path
----|--------|--------|----
  f |56.2MiB | 2y109d |DATA\3DSMaxInstall\Athena\Components\AGS\3.1\Autodesk Genuine Service.msi
  d |      0 |  2y74d |BUILDS\Install\Glue\User\CM Installer
  f |  168KiB|  2y337d| SOURCES\FireDrive\Data\File\ClicV2\9.0.0.1329\Bpk Pvt Inst.msm
  f | 15.3MiB|  2y347d| Finder\Perl58.zip
```

I tried below code:

```
...
df = pd.read_csv(s3_uri, sep=r'\s+\s', engine='python', names=["File", "Size", "Duration", "Path"])
...
```

But I don't get expected output. In my final output Duration & path is not splitted. I tried with some other regex pattern `++|(?<=\d\w)` but these are not working. As my files are huge in size (more than 1 GB) I would need your suggestions to perform this in best way. Also should I use some other native pandas parameters rather than using regex.

Comment: you probably want this instead, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: Thank you @gold_cy, Wiktor Stribiżew answer is perfect for you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(s3_uri, index_col=False, colspecs = [(0, 1), (1, 10), (10, 19), (19, -1)], names=["File", "Size", "Duration", "Path"])

print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
  File     Size Duration                                                                       Path
0    f  56.2MiB   2y109d  DATA\3DSMaxInstall\Athena\Components\AGS\3.1\Autodesk Genuine Service.msi
1    d        0    2y74d                                      BUILDS\Install\Glue\User\CM Installer
2    f   168KiB   2y337d             SOURCES\FireDrive\Data\File\ClicV2\9.0.0.1329\Bpk Pvt Inst.msm
3    f  15.3MiB   2y347d                                                          Finder\Perl58.zip
```

*Details*:

- [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) reads a table of fixed-width formatted lines into a data frame
- `index_col=False` - read in the first column as a data column, not an index column
- `colspecs = [(0, 1), (1, 10), (10, 19), (19, -1)]` - sets the column widths, the last one goes till the end of a line with `-1`
- `names=["File", "Size", "Duration", "Path"]` - the columns names.